# trigger Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

All i want to do is include the OLD.codeMaint variable which is in mcorr table in the message column in historique Table. 
But all what i got is this error when i try to modify the table :

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'MC35'.
```

btw MC35 is the row's that i want to modify primary key

This is my trigger code

```
 DELIMITER @@
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_update_mcorr @@
CREATE TRIGGER gmtt.after_update_mcorr
AFTER UPDATE ON gmtt.mcorr
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF OLD.etat = '0' AND NEW.etat = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO historique(message, User, dateHisto) VALUES ( 'a achevé la Maintenance '+ OLD.codeMaint , CURRENT_USER(), NOW()); 
   END IF;

END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, one uses `concat()` to concatenate strings:

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_update_mcorr @@

CREATE TRIGGER gmtt.after_update_mcorr
AFTER UPDATE ON gmtt.mcorr
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF OLD.etat = '0' AND NEW.etat = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO historique(message, User, dateHisto)
            VALUES (CONCAT('a achevé la Maintenance ', OLD.codeMaint), CURRENT_USER(), NOW()
                   ); 
   END IF;

END @@ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not recognise + as string concatenation operator. Use either `concat()` function or if you enable [pipes_as_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) sql mode, then you can use `||` operator to concatenate strings.